# How to short typeof expresion?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I have to check a lot of variables to exist and are defined. It looks like this one:

```
if (typeof store.part.items !== 'undefined' && 
  typeof domain !== 'undefined' && 
  typeof tab.partId !== 'undefined') 
{ 
  // do something useful 
}
```

It so boring to write that construction and takes a lot of taps to my keyboard every time, and increase a risk of error. How to short this problem?

Comment: You can simply use `x !== undefined` instead of using `typeof`. It's unlikely that somebody is going to overwrite `undefined`.

Comment: Do you also have to check that `store.part` and `store` exist before you can check `store.part.items`?

Comment: It's not possible to check if a variable is `undeclared` or not without using `typeof`, because `typeof` is an operator, not a function. Any undeclared value will throw an error if you use it as a parameter in a function call.

Comment: @HaoWu: It’s impossible for `store.part.items` to be undeclared, because it isn’t a name. Same with `tab.partId`. `domain` is the only one that could *potentially* be a declaredness check.

Comment: @Ry- But `domain` could be

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to collect all the parameters passed to the function as an array. Then, use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if they are all *non-undefined*

```
const defined = (...values) => values.every(v => typeof v !== "undefined")
```

or using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as suggested by @Ry

```
const defined = (...values) => !values.includes(undefined)
```

When calling the function, you don't have to create an array. You can simply call it with as many parameters as you like:

```
defined(store.part.items, domain, tab.partId)
```

Comment: Anyway, this can be simplified to `!values.includes(undefined)`. (Or `values.includes()`, but that’s weird.)

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho `every` also shortcircuits, just like `some`. Try 
`[1, 2, undefined].every(b => b.toString() === '1')` This will not throw an error because `toString` is never called on `undefined`. The callback returns false for 2 and the loop ends there

Comment: Correct @adiga! I was wrong in my thoughts here! I delete the comment to not confuse.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho No worries. You can always check the polyfill to verify the implementation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill

Comment: Yes, the polyfill show `if (!testResult) { return false; }` that means every does not nessecarily test every (that I first believed)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little function that helps me very much.

```
const defined = function (value) {
  const resFunc = (val) => typeof val !== 'undefined';

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    let res = true;

    value.forEach(el => res = res && resFunc(el));

    return res;
  }

  return resFunc(value);
}
```

And now my code looks more happy and readable:

```
if (defined([store.part.items, domain, tab.partId])) {
  // do something useful
}
```

Comment: You can use `.every` instead of `forEach` rather than reassigning `res`, if you wish

Comment: `res = res`? Why not just `res`? And why `.forEach` instead of `reduce` or `every`?

Comment: There is a missing ')' in the if. Should be ... ]) **)** { // do something useful

Comment: Can be used to test: `var store = {part: {items: []}}, domain = "http", tab = {partId: 123}`

Answer (score 1):

A refinement to OP's self-answer using `arguments` for a variable argument count and a plain old `for` loop and early-exit for performance:

```
const defined = function(...arguments) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] === undefined) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

// ...

if (defined(store.part.items, domain, tab.partId)) {
  // do something useful
}
if (defined(store.part.items) {
  // do something useful
}
```

Comment: `function(...arguments)` is a bit horrifying, to be honest :D Maybe pick another name?

Comment: Self answers is ok and sometimes forced by downvotes so the questioner has to find the answer. But here I saw the answer and question was made in the same minute. I saw it 13 min later. I think it is okay because only the quality of Q&A matter.

Comment: Missing `typeof`. Is `...arguments` nessecry? The `function()` has `arguments` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No shortcut exists for this. You require to define your own, this what I've come onto:

```js
function defined(objs, all=true) {
    return Array.prototype[all ? "every" : "some"]
                .call(objs, e => typeof e !== 'undefined')
           ? Array.isArray(objs) : !!exprs;
}
```

`all` enforces every object to be `undefined`, else a loose way is chosen.

Comment: nice variant, I think so. But there is not need in my case to check when any of exp is not defined. But thought is quite smart

Comment: `typeof exprs !== "undefined";` at the end doesn’t do anything, and this multipurpose function is kind of unpleasantly PHPesque.

Comment: But does cover all the cases anyways, so good @Ry-.